# How do polynomials with missing terms fit the definition of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

If polynomials are defined like this:

$$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2}\ \dots\ a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$$

Where each $a_i\in\mathbb{R}, a_n\neq0,$ and $n$ is a whole number.

Then how do polynomials with missing terms or degrees of $x$, like:

$$4x^4 + 3x^2 + x$$

fit the definition?

Why are they still polynomials despite skipped terms and degrees of $x$ matched with coefficients that aren’t equal to its degree?

Thank you.

Comment: Here you have a $ n=4$ degree polynomial,  where $a_0=0, a_1=1, a_2=3, a_3=0, a_4=4$

Comment: That helps some, thank you. I’m still confused because I expect the polynomial to conform to the pattern of decreasing by values of 1. How does $a_2 = 3$ still match the definition?

Comment: It matches the definition. The coefficients $a_n,a_{n-1},\ldots ,a_0$ are not the exponents! Indeed, the exponents decrease by $1$, provided its coefficient is nonzero. For example $a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$. But if some $a_i$ is zero, the whole term $a_ix^i$ vanishes, so there will be an "exponent gap". In your case, the terms $0\cdot x^3$ and $0\cdot x^0$ vanish, so we have $4x^4+3x^2+x$.

Comment: I understand now that the term $a_3 = 0$ means that $a_3x^3 = 0$, I just don’t understand how that fits the definition. If you start with a whole number and decrease it by steps of 1, how do you end up with $a_3 = 0$?

Comment: Not the $a_i$'s. The **exponents** in $x^4,x^3,x^2,...$ are decreasing by $1$. The $a_i$ are arbitrary (real) numbers. You wrote yourself "Where each $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$"

Comment: Right, thank you, I believe you that it matches. I’m almost there, but not quite. If the exponents are denoted by $n,\ n - 1,\ \dots\ 2, 1$, then why doesn’t each $a_i$ match the $n,\ n - 1,\ \dots\ 2, 1$ pattern? I see that $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, but… how are the exponents distinguished, if they follow the pattern of decrements by $1$?

Answer (score 1):

The definition is not $a_i=0$ for all $i$, it just talks about the leading coefficient $a_n$. So you want the term with leading degree to have non-zero coefficient, everything else can be any real number they want to.

And also I think you have a confusion in the sub index like $a_n$ stuff, it just is an arbitrary constant, like $a_0,a_1,\cdots a_n$ are just $n$ arbitrary things/ a sequence with $n$ numbers, they do not have any other restriction (generally). So like instead of using $a_i$'s you could use $\alpha,\beta$ and so on but you would run out of these alphabets pretty quickly, that is why we do not :)

Comment: This helps, thank you. I still don’t understand why the degree is expected to decrease by 1 while the coefficient can be anything, but you’re right about the confusion regarding the subsets. I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: Is this because the definition explicitly states that $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, whereas there is no such explicit definition of $x^i$?

Comment: @Dbs yeah, that is just the definition of a polynomial, it's just a sum of various degree x stuff multiplied by constant coefficients. try to write some random polynomials and see if they satisfy the definition. here i will start you off: $2x^4+x+9$, or $-x^3+x^2+x^7-9x$ and $x+x^3-3x^{6000}$

Comment: I’ll give that a try, it might take me a while. Thank you for helping explain, I understand better now.

Answer (score 0):

The term with $x^k$ is missing iff $a_k=0$. We can identify a polynomial with the sequence $a_0,a_1,\cdots ,a_k,0\cdots $. After $a_k$ we only have zeros.

Those sequences correspond $1-1$ with the polynomials. The largest index $k$ with $a_k\ne 0$ is called the degree of the polynomial, $a_k$ is called leading coefficient and $a_0$ the constant.

The special case is the sequence $0,0,0,\cdots$ corresponding with the zero-polynomial, usually considered to have degree $-\infty$.

This does not only work in the real numbers , but in every ring. The polynomials over a ring $R$ form the polynomial ring $R[X]$.

Comment: thank you for the additional explanation. I’ll try to work on it to close those gaps in my knowledge. Have a good day!